# Rails: Error installing Bcrypt using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, capistrano

I'm running `Ruby 2.3.0` and wish to deploy my `Rails` app to `Ubuntu 14` using `Capistrano 3`.

When executing `cap production deploy` I get the following error message:

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as
>   developer@[myVPS]: bundle exit status: 5 bundle stdout: An
>   error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.10), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'` succeeds
>   before bundling. bundle stderr: Nothing written

On my local machine (same Ruby version) `bcrypt 3.1.10` installs just fine.

When I login using `ssh developer@myvps` and directly run

`sudo gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'` I get:

> Fetching: bcrypt-3.1.10.gem (100%) 
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/ext/mri /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160305-7301-vt7ls4.rb extconf.rb
> ```
>
> creating Makefile
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/ext/mri make
>   "DESTDIR=" clean sh: 1: make: not found
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/ext/mri make
>   "DESTDIR=" sh: 1: make: not found
>
> make failed, exit code 127
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10 for inspection. Results logged
>   to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/bcrypt-3.1.10/gem_make.out

I'm new to all this, so not sure how to approach this. What should I do in this case?

Comment: pretty common problem. you will need to install the developer tools on your vps.   if ubuntu you need something like `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: can we see your Cap file? sanitized of course.

Comment: top comment worked perfectly for me with this problem - should be accepted answer?